# How to use create-vite to initialize a v2 project

Tags: npm, vite

I want to initialize a vite with react project so that it uses vite v2, not v3. I am trying the following command where "2.9.5" is the most recent v2 version of the create-vite util(https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-vite/v/2.9.5) but it does not work as expected and the resulting app has vite 3.1.0 in dependencies. How to fix it? Also, how to to do it with yarn?

`npm init vite@2.9.5 vite2app -- --template react`

Answer (score 0):

try using this command - npm create vite@2.9.5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).